# Error 400: Bad Request with requests.get() but same link working in Google Chrome

Tags: python, http, python-requests, get

I’m trying to get product data from Amazon link:

```
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/rcpublic/getprograms?countryCode=US&asin=B00T85IQOA&locale=en-US
```

On any browser that link gives back html fine but on python requests I get 400: bad request.

```
Import requests
Response = requests.get(‘https://sellercentral.amazon.com/rcpublic/getprograms?countryCode=US&asin=B00T85IQOA&locale=en-US’)
Print(Response)
```

I tried changing the user agent but it doesn’t seem to do anything
Thank you

Comment: This cannot be your real code, because `Import` and `Print` are capitalized when they should not be.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Yes you are correct because I were not need my computer when I wrote this post so I just wrote the code I used…

Answer (score 1):

It seems you must include some headers (User-Agent and Server) in order to receive a response.

Here is a code sample that returns the same JSON response that you see in the browser:

```
import requests

url = "https://sellercentral.amazon.com/rcpublic/getprograms"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Python", 
    "Server": "Server"
}
params = {
    "countryCode": "US",
    "asin": "B00T85IQOA",
    "locale": "en-US"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

print(r.json())
```